# Can I take trains in Finland even if it shows sold out?

Tags: trains, bookings, finland, interrail

I'll travel in Finland using my Interrail card but when I check the trains schedule I find all sold out! What should I do? Can I go and take the train anyway?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This heavily depends on the type of train you are planning to use.

In general there are 5 different type of trains you can use with your Interrail/Eurail pass

- **regional trains** which are included in a pass and **no reservations** are possible
- trains with reservations available but **not compulsory**. If you don't buy such a reservation before boarding the train you might not get a seat at all.
- you are not allowed to board trains with **compulsory** reservation without one. There is mostly only a limited contingent of reservations available for rail pass holders (typically high speed and night trains)
- sometimes you are only granted a **discount** on standard ticket fares. (E.g. Eurostar and Thalys)
- some trains in Europe such as hotel trains for example **don't offer any discount** for rail pass holders

There are the following train categories operating in finland:

- *Yöjunat* (night train) and *Pendolino* (highspeed train) **require reservations**. You can't take those trains if they are already sold out.
- For intercities  (*IC*) **reservations** are only **recommended**. The odds are high that you might not get a seat on this train if it is already booked up.
- *Pikajunat* (P) and *Taajamajuna (H)* are interregional and regional trains and do **not require** reservations. Just board those trains!

You can actually find details on reservations organized by country on [interrail.eu](https://www.interrail.eu/en/plan-your-trip/trains-europe/trains-country/trains-finland)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Now I know it is intercities train and I want to know if the tickets they sell are with numbers ?
I mean if I can just take the train and find a free seat even it shows sold out ?

Comment: @ROS_OPENCV You can board the train, but if it's sold out, it's very unlikely that there are free seats like Daniel said. Seating reservations are compulsory with single tickets (non-interrail, non-commuter) and canceling a ticket is expensive so everyone who has reserved a seat is very likely to show up. There are cars that have non-reserved seats for commuters, but again, if the entire train is sold out those cars will be full too. Especially if you're travelling right before or after a holiday (Christmas, New Year) you'll have to prepare for standing on the aisle the entire journey.