# How to know train reservation prices at Interrail online reservation service?

Tags: trains, europe, bookings, interrail

Me and a couple of friends bought Interrail passes for our Summer trip this year. I was trying to make some train reservations at https://reservations.interrail.eu/ , but the process doesn't seem to be transparent at all.

As an example, I selected this options for one of the reservations:
  [image: prices]

How can I know the prices of each of the accommodation preferences I selected? The page states that the prices are indicative, but I'd like to know how much each alternative would cost me, in order to decide which of them is more suitable to our budget...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
As I was suggested to use other reservation services, here are the trips that need reservation AFAIK:

- Milan - Venice
- Venice - Vienna (night train)
- Vienna - Budapest -> I won't use this one to sleep in (only a 2h
  trip), but it will be a night train, so reservation is required...
- Zagreb - Split (night train)

Comment: Don't make reservations on that website, go to the respective train companies' websites! Generally, you don't have to reserve every train, only reserve those that go a long distance or overnight for example.

Comment: Maybe you could include a list of trains/routes you wish to travel, then we can help you more.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian. I tried to check prices at other sites but didn't succeed for most of the cases. I've added information about the trips I'm making, if you or anyone could help me with that.

Comment: Budapest-Vienna is 6 hours, not 2. In my opinion, you are missing out on a lot by taking night trains where the scenery at day time would be fascinating (Alps, Croatia...). Are you flexible enough to take the day trips?
Anyways, Milan-Venice should be trenitalia.it, Venice-Vienna is OEBB. The other two might be problematic.

Comment: I really won't have enough time to visit every country and still travel during the day... About the Vienna-Budapest, according to the train schedules, it's slightly under 2h30 (http://i.imgur.com/0mg1ZPM.png). I noticed I wrote it wrong in the original post (I wrote Budapest-Zagreb where it was supposed to be Vienna-Budapest).

Comment: Thanks for those two suggestions anyway @Sebastian. About the other two, I am indeed having a bit more difficulty... I tried to check Vienna-Budapest at OBB, but I can't make reservation only, and the same at ACP Rail (when I select "Reservation only", it throws an error...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61546/discussion-between-norim-13-and-sebastian).

Comment: Please have a look on my answer to another question for more information on which trains have compulsary reservations: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/60219/19017

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. My problem isn't so much which trains to reserve, but how to do it... As I stated before, right now I'm having a hard time finding how to reserve the Vienna-Budapest train...

Comment: As stated in my answer below, the best option to buy reservations is at a station in the respective country. Some countries allow you to buy reservations online, some allow you to buy them via phone.

Answer (score 2):

[rail.cc](http://rail.cc) offers a crompehensive overview on interrail reservation fees across Europe.
Unfortunately each railway organization handles reservations differently. Therefore my best advise would be to buy reservations within the respective countries directly at train stations (or sometimes even get free reservations).

Reservations are one of the reasons interrail travel remains an adventure, as not everything will always happen as planned...

Comment: Do you think it will be ok if I make reservations only one or two days in advance at the train stations? Do the trains often get fully booked? I like the adventure part of the process right until it makes me loose money from my hotel reservations and flights :P

Comment: For night trains (especially in the summer months June-August) this could be a risky bet. You could try to buy a reservation at your local train station. In some constelations this could be possible.
But the Railjet between Budapest and Vienna for example doesn't even have compulsory reservations. That means you might always board the train with your interrail ticket, but in the worst case you won't get a seat.(This is now your decision, if you have a problem with sitting somewhere on the floor - for me this still counts onto adventure ^^)

Comment: The Railjet doesn't require reservation, but we were planning on taking the  
NT 347, which takes much less time (under 2h30), and that requires reservation... But even on the interrail reservations service no price is displayed... http://i.imgur.com/EUIySbT.png

Comment: @norim_13 has reservation fee information for most trains (including NT 347), just navigate to Interrail/Night trains / Austria / NT 347 and you get detailed information on https://rail.cc/en/interrail-night-train/vienna-bucharest-en-347/50 so it's 10€ for a normal seat

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. But although this tells me the price, I can't find a way to purchase it... I can't find in OEBB's site the option to reserve seats for GlobalPass owners...